# Easy way to store MP3 file-path to variable and read from another class?

Tags: java, file, variables

I'm trying to create a MP3 player program and I need a way to store the file-path of the mp3 in a variable so I can load the variable in another class and play that file. Current code block for save/load is .txt now, but I need to replace it with the variable save.

```
try {
      // What to do with the file.
      textarea.read( new FileReader( file.getAbsolutePath() ), null );
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.out.println("Problem accessing file"+file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("File access cancelled.");
}
```

I'm using these imports in the class reading the variable,

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.*;
import javazoom.jl.player.*;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.newdawn.slick.openal.Audio;
import org.newdawn.slick.openal.AudioLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.openal.SoundStore;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;
```

As well as the import for the class in question.

Comment: From the class you are reading the file you can initiate playing the file, so from the current class from where you are reading the file you already have the variable in place.

Now to play the file you can make instance of the class which plays your file.

Comment: Thank you Shaikh, I edited and it turns out that I did exactly that.

Comment: Please add it as answer and accept it to close your question.

Comment: Please don't put [solved] in the title or post the answer in the question. Simply post your answer and then accept it; that is how a question is answered.

Comment: It says that I have to wait a day before accepting my own answer. :P I'll get on it asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        try{

            FileInputStream mp3 = new FileInputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
            Player playMP3 = new Player(mp3);

            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);

} }   
}
```